# Is there a API endpoint or method to read out Ms Graph API documentation of different types

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/intents
I'm using this endpoint for example to read out security baselines. But i'm using multiple endpoints like device configurations, etc.

sample response:
 `{ "id": "179b76c7-5d9c-4842-8588-2ca998af1013", "displayName": "SuperVision - Windows 10 Security Baseline", "description": null, "isAssigned": true, "isMigratingToConfigurationPolicy": null, "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-10-06T09:37:45.2868285Z", "templateId": "034ccd46-190c-4afc-adf1-ad7cc11262eb", "roleScopeTagIds": [ "0" ] },`

I don't want to show 'isMigratingToConfigurationPolicy' in the output of my application.
I want to show the description of this setting, like the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-deviceintent-devicemanagementintent?view=graph-rest-beta#properties

Is there any way to read out these descriptions of these settings?

I tried to use this repo:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib

and match the .md files to the security baselines. But it did not work as expected.